# I want to change the selection of the drop down by its option's name

Tags: jquery, select

I have this select drop down box:

```
    <select id="garden">
      <option value="1">Flowers</option>
      <option value="2">Shrubs</option>
      <option value="3">Trees</option>
      <option value="4">Bushes</option>
      <option value="5">Grass</option>
      <option value="6">Dirt</option>
    </select>
```

I want to change the selection of this drop down by its option's name (i.e Trees).

Comment: I suggest you to make a little bit clearer questions.

Comment: simply want to select this drop down with its name i.e. Trees. i have Trees with me and want to change this drop down to trees

Comment: i still dont get you. You want to set Trees as default(selected) option in dropdown onload? Or to retrieve text after you select some of the value in dropdown?

Comment: dont want change drop down on onLoad but want to change drop down  afterwards with Trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery way:

```
$("select#garden option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Trees") $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    else $(this).removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Traditional JavaScript way:

```
var select = document.getElementById("#garden");
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].innerText == "Trees") select.options[i].selected = "selected";
    else select.options[i].selected = false;
}
```

Comment: this also works, if that is his desire: $("#garden option:contains(Trees)").prop('selected',true);

Comment: if i use contains then one problem is getting that its not matching with exact string. i.e. if he finds "Trees All" first then it select this one not only "Trees"

Comment: Maybe even better to set the attribute "selected" to "false" in an else clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value by the name with javascript in following way...

```
var val = document.getElementByName("garden").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery for that

```
var x = $('#my-select-id option:selected').text();
```

Comment: This code will give you the text of the selected option. I believe he wants the oposite: To select an option given it's text. I think the best way would be looping through the option text's and selecting the right one